# Impossible to access Heroku config vars from python code

Tags: python, django, heroku, config

I am trying to deploy my django app on Heroku, but the issue is that I cannot access my config vars from python code.

Here are my config vars (obfuscated for obvious reasons)

```
$ heroku config --remote production
=== myapp Config Vars
DATABASE_URL:                   postgres://<removed>
DJANGO_DEBUG:                   0
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: <removed>
SECRET_KEY:                     <removed>
```

Now, in my django settings.py, the  code

```
import os
os.environ["DJANGO_DEBUG"]
```

for example results in an error because the key "DJANGO_DEBUG" is nowhere to be found in the dictionary `os.environ`.

My question is: how can I access Heroku config variables in production?

I have tried the package python-decouple, but it is not able to access the config vars neither. (Locally, my variables are put in a .env file and are accessible with the help of the package python-decouple)

Edit: I actually realized that the config variables are accessible from my app and from the command *if* I run bash from within the app page on heroku, but there are not accessible if I run python on an ssh session, i.e., if I run python like this:

```
$heroku ps:exec
$python
```

`os.environ` does not contain my config variables.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the original OP. Turns out the problem was the way I was accessing the remote terminal session. The correct way to do it to have all the config vars accessible is

```
heroku run bash
```

as opposed to

```
heroku ps:exec
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the config vars for a Heroku application in the settings of the App. Click the **Settings** Tab then navigate to the **Config Vars** section. Click **Reveal Config Vars** and enter the key pair values for your variables.

These will get injected into your application.

Comment: I can access config vars from the website just fine, what I am not able to do is have access to them from python.